# implementation of minimax for connect four in lua

Tags: algorithm, lua, artificial-intelligence, coronasdk, minimax

I'm making Connect Four game in Corona sdk and want to make a AI player using minimax when user select playing with computer. I found minimax [Minimax for Lua](https://github.com/kennyledet/Algorithm-Implementations/blob/master/Minimax/Lua/Yonaba/minimax.lua) to assistance but I'm stuck with tree building.

My question is how can I make tree to pass this algorithm and assign the values to each node of tree because I guess in this case each node value is -1(loose) or +1(win) and find the target column of Connect Four? I'm thinking tree will look like for minimax

```
local t = tree() -- tree() creates the new tree for minimax
t:addNode('A',nil,0) -- head node
t:addNode('B1','A',0)
t:addNode('B2','A',0)
t:addNode('B3','A',0)

t:addNode('C1','B1',4)
t:addNode('C2','B1',12)
t:addNode('C3','B1',7)

t:addNode('C4','B2',10)
t:addNode('C5','B2',5)
t:addNode('C6','B2',6)

t:addNode('C7','B3',1)
t:addNode('C8','B3',2)
t:addNode('C9','B3',3)
```

Do I need to build a tree each time after a move with arbitrary combinations? How can I decide the best score for each move?

I hope this informations are enough to understand my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MinMax doesn't require actually building a tree. The tree is only the basic structure of the possible moves. Actually it's rather contraproductive to build the tree everytime - you should rather implicitly traverse the tree of possible moves. This tutorial might help: http://neverstopbuilding.com/minimax.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @Paul, I will check the tutorial.

Actually I was thinking to build a MinMax implementation for universal purpose, just make a tree once and achieve AI for any kind of game which require MinMax. Can I find any track like this?

Thanks for understanding.